# Outlined Edit Text from Material Design

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, material-design, android-textinputlayout

How can I implement an outlined text field (as shown on [this material design page](https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html#outlined-text-field))?
[image: Activated Edit Text]

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Read [**`Outline Box`**](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/)  .

> Outline text fields have a stroked border and are less emphasized. To
> use an outline text field, apply the following style to your
> TextInputLayout:

```
 style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
```

**Dependencies**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

**XML**

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
   android:id="@+id/name_text_input"
   style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >

   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
       android:id="@+id/name_edit_text"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="@string/label_name" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

[**`DEMO`**](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-111-kotlin/#2)

### FYI

Legacy support ended in Android 28 . Now onward use

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
```

Comment: I am not sure about this but maybe the correct style name is "@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlineBox" instead of the above style replace OutlinedBox with OutlineBox. It may help me if you plz brief about this.

Comment: How to set text in `TextInputEditText` field? @Subhank Gupta programmtically

Comment: FYI: legacy support ended in Android 28 . now onward use `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'`

Comment: use the new tags    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout> & <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>

Answer (score 16):

**UPDATE**

Also working fine with

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Using **`implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'`**  I'm getting below error

> Cannot resolve symbol '@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlineBox'

[image]

## Solution

Make below changes in your **`Build.Gradle`**

Use **`compileSdkVersion 28`**

Use **`targetSdkVersion 28`**

Use Below dependencies

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

Sample code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.dangarmahesh.demoapp.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_height="250dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/userIDTextInputLayout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/userIDTextInputEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="User ID" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/passwordTextInputLayout"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordTextInputEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="LOGIN"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTOUT**

[image]

Comment: Will this negatively affect android api 27 and below phones that have the app installed?

Comment: @OrimDominic *`Will this negatively affect android api 27`*   No  i have tested it in API 26 also

Answer (score 11):

With the **migration** to androidx libraries **you have to use** the new [Material Components for android library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

Use the [`TextInputLayout`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md#filled-box-default) component:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_text">

  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And apply this style:

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
```

[image]

**Requirements:**

- you have to add [this dependencies](http://Material%20Components%20theme) in your `build.gradle` file

  `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>'`
- apply a [Material Components theme](http://Material%20Components%20theme)

  `<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">`

Comment: But the color won't change when it is  not focused

Comment: @AbrahamMathew Use the `boxStrokeColor` attribute. Use a **selector** like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57790851/2016562).

Comment: Dont be careful 1)xml viewer not good visualization this 2) dont set hint for TextInputEditText 3)for normal view u click on edit text if not have text 4)parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*" ofc 5)style add in TextInputLayout

Answer (score 10):

You need to add this dependency to your "module level" **build.gradle** **`com.google.android.material`** to use latest **`material UI components`**.

Use this style in your **`com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`** then,

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
```

Checkout from [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/)

---

> If you're using **`com.android.support:design`** library then you
>   should change your app style to `Theme.MaterialComponents...Bridge`
>   *(I.e. like change style from `Theme.AppCompat.Light` to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge`)*
>
> first,
>
> Next, you have to use this style in your
>   **`android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`**:
>
> ```
> style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="First Name"/>
 </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **appcompact** library then you can go with this **android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout**

if you are using **ANDROIDX** build so I come to one conclusion who is having latest code according to android jetpack.

For using this you need to have this dependencies in your app gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
}
```

then this way you can add to your xml for the UI element

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/messageTextInputLayout"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordTextInputEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Text here" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **OutlinedTextField**( with **Jetpack Compose** ) in android-

[image]

```
            OutlinedTextField(
                                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                                    value = textState.value,
                                    onValueChange = {
                                        textState.value = it
                                        viewModel.setSteps(stepNo.plus(1), it.text)
                                    },
                                    label = {
                                        Text(text = "Step ".plus(stepNo.plus(1)).plus("..."))
                                    },
                                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
                                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                                        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent
                                    ),
                                    trailingIcon = {
                                            IconButton(onClick = {}) {
                                            Icon(
                                                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 10.dp),
                                                imageVector = Icons.Filled.Image,
                                                tint = Color.Blue,
                                                contentDescription = "Select Image"
                                            )
                                        }
                                    }
                                )
```

Jetpack Compose Sample Codes- https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2021/08/03/jetpack-compose-1-0-0-sample-codes/