# Material TextInputLayout styles are not working

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

Material TextInputLayout styles are not working.

I followed the documentation on material textinputlayout here:
https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:hint="@string/app_name"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

With gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'
```

Using the style OutlinedBox, I expect to have the layout to have an outline but instead it just shows a plain TextInputLayout.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52459726/7666442

Comment: Try with `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: You have to extend the material theme in your `AppTheme` for example `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge`

Comment: I've already done that

Comment: @GabLedesma hve run your code in device or XML

Comment: @NileshRathod On preview it's not working. I'll try running it on my device, hold on.

Comment: @NileshRathod it's working when I run it. But on preview it's not. Weird. Thanks anyways!

Comment: there is some rendering issue. like 3 of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it's not working on preview, I had to run it on a device to see the real output. Thanks to @NileshRathod

I hope that android fixes this

Comment: Please take note that the Android team doesn't own the [Material Components for Android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) library. It's _developed by a core team of engineers and UX designers at Google_ (see https://github.com/material-components/material-components#material-components-shared-documentation-and-policies)

Answer (score 3):

Change your `styles.xml` `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`

You can use below code:

```xml
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my assumption, The problem is due to the Appcompat theme. You must change it to materialCompontents.DayNight.

Change your style.xml file to like this,

```js
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

And change your TextInputLayout Code as follows:

```js
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#252734"
            android:hint="Enter Name" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Sometimes it will not work in the ui designer of android studio. But it will surely work on real devices.

Answer (score 0):

It will work only on Material Component.
It will not work on Theme.AppCompat, if any of the style uses this it will not work.
So change all the Theme.AppCompat to Theme.MaterialComponents on your style.xml
Like

> Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar

Answer (score 0):

Also, be sure you have selected the correct theme in your xml

[image]