# Android how to change text input background image

Tags: android-layout, material-design

I have the following code for the input text

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_login_screen_input_container">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/input_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="Name"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

After adding the android:background, the input text becomes:
[image]

As you see, i added the rounded container as a background image, but the input text box still has the rectangular box behind it. My ultimate goal is to create a input text box like this:
[image]

Then when user start typing in the box, the input text box should becomes:
[image]

Please let me know how i should achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem by enabling Material Design as suggested by @Mohammad (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52401339/9793695), however, i also need to follow instruction in ([Updating com.android.support libraries v7:26.+ to v7:28.0.0 throw Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54264190/updating-com-android-support-libraries-v726-to-v728-0-0-throw-multiple-dex-f/54264401?noredirect=1#comment95353479_54264401)) to resolve all the dependencies first. Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Use **compileSdkVersion 28**

Use **targetSdkVersion 28**

**Dependencies**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

Add this code

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/userIDTextInputLayout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/userIDTextInputEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Email or Username" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

add    `android:background="@drawable/ic_login_screen_input_container"` inside `EditText` and remove it from  `TextInputLayout` *OR* `add android:background="@null"` to your `EditText`

Comment: i tried your suggestion, but doesn't work, it behave the same as i reported above

Comment: I found out this line of code put it in your textinputlayout as a style it will give you the outline box style 'style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"'

Comment: It is not resolvable, do you include any library?

Comment: I tried that but got a merge dex error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException ...