# Updating com.android.support libraries v7:26.+ to v7:28.0.0 throw Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to upgrade dependencies from v:7:26.+ to v:7.28.0.0, sync is okay, but Multiple dex error is thrown when I try to run the app, i am not sure what it is complaining, tried to update the multidex dependency from 1.0.1 to 1.0.3 as well but doesn't help. Please help!

> Error: Multiple dex files define
>   Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;

**My App Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.findme"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    // Temporary fix until alpha10
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    //implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

    //implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    /**
     * https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife
     * Avoid findViewById calls by using @BindView on field
     * note: cannot go to 10.10.0, require min sdk 26
     */
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    // for firebase and firestore
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'

    // for LinkedIn
    compile project(path: ':linkedin-sdk')

    // for facebook
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'

    // for BLE

    //implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.15+'

    //implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.15.2'
    compile(name: 'android-beacon-library-more-reliable-service-stop2-1-g7dbb6b3', ext: 'aar')

    // life cycle
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0"

    // *** Jetpack ***

    //

    // Release note https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes

    // for ROOM
    implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.4'
    def room_version = "1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"

    // for work manager
    def work_version = "1.0.0-alpha09"
    implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:$work_version"

    // *** End of JackPack ***

    // for google play service (location)
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'

    // for google login
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'

    // for fire storage
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'

    // for image

    //implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28+'

    // for crashlytics
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'

    // for bugfender
    implementation 'com.bugfender.sdk:android:1.+'

    // userful method
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**My project gradle**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            // for crashlytics
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'

        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' // google-services plugin
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        // for crashlytics
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'

    }
}



allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        // for crashlytics
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }

        flatDir {
            dirs 'src/main/libs'
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: press double shift in Android studio and just enter `ListenableFuture`. It will say, which library contain this class.

Comment: One or more of your dependencies is using AndroidX. You can't mix AndroidX and the legacy support libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, double shift pop up and showed that it is related to Gradle__com_google_guava_listenablefuture_1_0_jar.xml under workFolder/.idea/libraries , but i dont recall i am using it anywhere. I tried to update this lib to     implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre' but it require a min version of 26. i would like to keep the min version on 21. So how would i resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**: Excluding Guava group with `listenablefuture` module from current transitive dependency

```
implementation("android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha09") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture' 
}
```

Also, use this configuration for linkedin-sdk:

```
api project(path: ':linkedin-sdk') {
    transitive = true
}
```

**Reason**:

As per [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116154359),

It is surprisingly done on purpose! ([reference](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/guava-announce/Km82fZG68Sw)) Yet new release of Guava will be available soon, with of course resolve issue. For now, excluding as stated above should work perfectly.

Comment: after adding above, i got this error : Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/volley/ExecutorDelivery$1;

and if i upgrade to volley 1.1.1 (implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'), i got a different error: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/volley/VolleyError;

Comment: Did it work? If yes, would you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: now i got the new error: Could not find method project() for arguments [{path=:linkedin-sdk}, build_6j6qdbojr6qqs3dxvzcqagnos$_run_closure2$_closure7@70bd7766] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: just declare `api project(':linkedin-sdk')` instead of `api project(parth: ':linkedin-sdk')`

Comment: Now it goes back to the same volley multi dex error: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/volley/ExecutorDelivery$1;

Comment: Use volley version 1.1.1 instead of 1.1.0

Comment: yes i tried both version and it throw the same error... fyi after i update the version, i did a Clean, Rebuild then Run

Actually the error message is slightly different: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/volley/VolleyError;

Comment: go to linkedin-sdk subdirectory and delete volley.jar file

Comment: No luck... Transform output file /Users/spiderloop/Documents/workspace/AndroidStudio/jugo-android/linkedin-sdk/libs/volley.jar does not exist.

Comment: Remove volley dependency from your own app level build.gradle file and set `transitive = true` for linkedin-sdk

Comment: New error : Could not set unknown property 'transitive' for project ':linkedin-sdk' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: This resolve problem:
compile(project(path: ':linkedin-sdk')) {transitive = true} AND comment out all volley specific lines AND keeping the linkedin SDK volley.jar file.

can you update the solution and i will mark it resolve

One question i have is how would i use latest volley in this case?

Comment: I've updated the question. Glad that you resolved it :)
I'll do the dependency flow myself and let you know how to resolve conflict with latest version of volley..