# customize Bounding box stroke in TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android, material-components

I'm trying to change box Stroke Color of `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout` while not focused but there is no attribute for that this is my `TextInputLayout` code

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/white"
    app:boxStrokeWidth="1dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTxt_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint_email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

and I searched for a way to change its color and found this link :
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/112

so i tried using this line in my colors file

```
<color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color" tools:override="true">#fff</color>
```

this solved the problem and changed stroke box color but **the issue here is that i want to change this color in other TextInputLayouts in the same app !!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the box stroke color just use the **`app:boxStrokeColor`** attribute in the xml.

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/mySelector"
        ../>
```

You should use a selector. It is the default:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.87" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_hovered="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

You can also use a custom style:

```
  <style name="MyOutlinedBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/text_input_selector</item>
  </style>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: @AbrahamMathew Which version of the library are you using? In any case you can use your favorite color, it is just the default selector posted as an example.

Comment: Using      implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

Comment: @AbrahamMathew Use the 1.1.0 of the library or just replace with your favorite color.

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0

Comment: @AbrahamMathew Check the [official doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases). The latest version is implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta02'

Comment: Good solution, but in my case label when inputing text not change color. How fix it? i use com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1 (now its latest stable )

Comment: solution: add app:hintTextColor="@color/red"