# Material TextInputLayout - style `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox` change box unfocused color

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout

I am using material `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout` in application. I want to change the box outline color when the `TextInputEditText` does not have focus.

I've already tried setting `colorControlNormal`, `colorControlActivated`, `colorControlHighlight` in styles, but they do not seem to work. Only focused color changes, unfocused color does not change. Moreover, I also tried adding `colorOnSurface` in styles, but this attribute seems to be in-existent in stable version.

Someone's help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57790851/7666442

Comment: Yes, as I said, `colorOnSurface` attribute is non-existent in the library. Project does not compile if I add this attribute.

Comment: You should replace `colorOnSurface` with your  required color like  `@color/YourColor`

Comment: Nilesh, I do understand that thing, but `colorOnSurface` attribute does not exist. `colorOnSurface` attribute could not be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use latest `dependencies` of `material` library

Use this one

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'
```

Comment: This is not a stable version, and it is not advisable and recommended to use alpha version in application.

Comment: @parekhkruti26 its depends on your requirements, BTW i'm using alpha version in my application